# Create models in Django using AWS S3 data and point to them

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create models in Django using existing data in AWS S3

```
def create_model(**kwargs):
    return Video.objects.create(**kwargs)

for s3_object_mp4 in my_bucket.objects.all():

    path_mp4, key_mp4 = os.path.split(s3_object_mp4.key)
    create_model(video_name=str('key_mp4'),
                         video_url='??')
```

And I used this to point to the created data:

```
client = boto3.client('s3', 'eu-central-1')
url = client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': key_mp4}, ExpiresIn=604800)
```

Two questions here:

1) If this link will expire, does that mean on expiration I have to delete, and re-populate my models every 7 days as max ?

2) Will amazon then charge everytime a user watches a video on the html (url) ? and then another time when repopulating the whole database because the links expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your pre-signed URLs will expire. Deleting and re-populating the models is one option. Another option would be to perform an `update` in place.

2) S3 is priced on the data stored and the requests. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232199/263421) the generation of pre-signed URLs is entirely client-side and therefore free.

Comment: can you kindly provide an example for update in place ?

Comment: @Matthew, you'll find the docs for saving models here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

Comment: so updating the urls are free, thanks for the link to the other answer.  Because on "retrieval" is what cost money. And I am not sure what does retrieval mean in this case. Is viewing those videos on AWS using the URL is then that costs money ?

Comment: Yes. You'll be billed for both the retrieval and the data transfer (see "Data Transfer OUT From Amazon S3 To Internet"): https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/