# Access Private S3 Bucket From Another S3 Bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a React app deployed to an S3 bucket and I've another private S3 bucket where I store images and documents within the same AWS account. Currently, I display images on the frontend using AWS Signed URLs, but this approach is not ideal. Is there a way for my website bucket to internally access the storage bucket, keeping the storage bucket private and allowing access to files without expiration or the need for signed URLs?

Comment: You're currently using signed URLs because, presumably, these are not public objects. Are you intending for them to remain private and only available to authenticated clients?

Comment: Please tell us more about why you think "this approach is not ideal".

Comment: Your website can use API calls to Amazon S3 using an AWS SDK. By providing AWS credentials, the API calls will let your app access private content in Amazon S3 buckets. This is great when the app wants to access the objects itself, but not if you want to provide a URL to users to access the objects because your app would need to 're-serve' the files to users, thereby adding a lot of work for your app.

Comment: that's correct @jarmod

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That approach is not ideal because, let's say I'm displaying all the users in a table with 50 users per page. This requires calling the AWS API 50 times, leading to performance issues. Additionally, using signed URLs poses a security risk as they contain some of my AWS credentials.

Comment: Creating a pre-signed URL is a call to an SDK but it's not an API request to an AWS service. You can do a simple test to create 100s of URLs to see how long it takes. On the 'credentials are in the pre-signed URL' concern, the access key is in the URL, not the full credentials. The access key is not a secret and it's not usable on its own.

Comment: Quick test with the AWS JavaScript SDK v3: creating 1000 unique pre-signed GET URLs took about 600ms. Also, see [How secure are Amazon AWS Access keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678835/how-secure-are-amazon-aws-access-keys) and [Does generating a pre-signed URL to an S3 object using the AWS SDK cost anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231229)

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront distribution is the best way to go.

- [full contro over cookies and signedURL both supported here, no need of S3 features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html)
- Better caching at edge
- Security
- CORS handling
- and many more
- more safety from attacks

Just check once here, we use this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html